# Find high and low in Java 8

Tags: java, list, parallel-processing, java-8, java-stream

I was testing different ways to search for a low and high values inside a list in Java and I realized that the results using the stream() and parallelStream() methods slower and less performant are than just iterate through the list...

is this possible?
how is this possible?

here is my code:

iterating whole array:

```
    private HighLowTuple calculateIteratingWholeArray( List<Integer> arrayWithNumbers,         int from, int to )
        {

    // long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    HighLowTuple result = new HighLowTuple( -1, Integer.MAX_VALUE );
    for( int i = from; i < to; i++ )
    {

        int value = arrayWithNumbers.get( i );

        if( value > result.high )
        {
            result.high = value;
        }

        if( value < result.low )
        {
            result.low = value;
        }

    }
    // long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
    // System.out.println( "duration internal calculateIteratingWholeArray from " + from +
    // " to + " + to + "  "
    // + ( end - start ) + " ms" );
    return result;
}
```

and here the code using java 8 streams:

```
     private HighLowTuple calculateUsingStreamParallel( List<Integer> arrayWithIntegers )
{
    HighLowTuple result = new HighLowTuple( -1, Integer.MAX_VALUE );

    Consumer<Integer> highlow = new Consumer<Integer>()
    {

        @Override
        public void accept( Integer number )
        {
            if( result.high < number )
                result.high = number;

            if( result.low > number )
                result.low = number;

        }
    };
    arrayWithIntegers.stream().parallel().forEach( highlow );
    return result;
}
```

Comment: How big were your lists? Have you tried different sizes?

Comment: This should probably be on :
http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: What *kind* of lists?

Comment: Why do you assume that the new stream based APIs would always be faster than the old approaches?  They usually aren't.

Answer (score 8):

Before you start thinking about performance you should think about *correctness*. You are using a *parallel* stream with a custom, stateful `Consumer` that is not thread-safe:

```
if( result.high < number )
// if another thread updates ⟨high⟩ right at this point you might loose a value
    result.high = number;

if( result.low > number )
// again, possible loss of values here
    result.low = number;
```

Further, unless you have declared the variables `HighLowTuple.high` and `HighLowTuple.low` as `volatile`, the JVM’s optimizations may cause even more loss of updates when you use it multi-threaded without synchronization. But *if* you have declared them `volatile` you should not be surprised about lower performance (while still having incorrect code).

---

The solution is to learn about the API first. You have re-invented the wheel as there is already a concise way of finding high and low in Java 8:

```
IntSummaryStatistics s = arrayWithIntegers.stream()
  .parallel().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).summaryStatistics();
// if you still like your tuple class:
return new HighLowTuple(s.getMax(), s.getMin());
```

But, of course, if you have an array of `int` values it would be even more efficient to use an `IntStream` out of it instead of making the detour to the `Collection` of `Integer`:

```
IntSummaryStatistics s = IntStream.of(array).parallel().summaryStatistics();
```

Comment: is not reinventing the wheel, is just that summaryStatistics is not performant at all

Comment: @danibuiza: that’s an empty claim as when you wrote the question you didn’t even know about `summaryStatistics()` not to speak of making reliable performance tests with it.